# How do I fix title?

Tags: wp-title

my title appears as home-title, I'm trying to remove but it's not working 
code in header.php is

```
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' );?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <?php
    wp_head(); /** we hook up in wp_booster @see td_wp_booster_functions::hook_wp_head */
    ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

Usage of `wp_title()` is not recommended anymore. Instead, you can add the `title-tag` support to your theme, so WordPress can automatically build and output the proper title for you. Here's how to do it:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse302145_add_title_tag' );
function wpse302145_add_title_tag() {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
```

This piece of code goes in your theme/child-theme's `functions.php` file. You can safely remove the `<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>` line from the theme's header now.

Comment: problem not fixed